# tail -n 50 -f debug.log

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I am downloading the Bitcoin blockchain from Bitcoin-Core using rasberry pi and I have been successful so far and wanted to check the debug.log just to check that it was going okay:

```
tail -n 50 -f debug.log
```

Now I want to return to the root file so that I can install Tor but I am hesitant to do this from the screen running debug.log because I dont want to stop the download. I was hoping someone here could give me an easy way to do this while the debug.log still runs in the `/mnt/data` file that I have created

Comment: Open a new shell window? Open a new vty? Hit Ctrl/c to interrupt the `tail`?

Comment: Hitting ^C to end `tail`? Actually, what are you actually asking for?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am downloading the Bitcoin blockchain from Bitcoin-Core using rasberry pi and I have been successful so far and wanted to check the debug.log just to check that it was going okay. Now I want to return to the root file so that I can install Tor but I am hesitant to do this from the screen running debug.log bcoz I dont want to stop the download. I was hoping someone on this forum could give me an easy way to do this while the debug.log still runs in the /mnt/data file that I have created.

Comment: `tail -n 50 -f debug.log` does not download anything, it only outputs last 50 lines of `debug.log` in realtime. You can start it or interrupt at any time to watch the log file.

Comment: Thanks Everyone! Much Appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command

```
tail -n 50 -f debug.log
```

will show the last 50 lines of debug.log, and then continue to show further lines as they arrive into `debug.log` (`-f` means to "follow" the file `debug.log`).

If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, as has been suggested, you will simply quit the `tail` command, i.e. stop "following" the file `debug.log`. It will not in any way terminate the application that generates text into `debug.log`.

Once you have terminated the `tail` command, you'll get your prompt back, and can continue with other commands.